# Query to filter results that must have all the values of an array

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Looking to query and filter results by passing an array as an arguement and retrieving records that have atleast all the elements being passed.

```
Document 1
    {
        values: [1, 4, 5]
    }

Document 2
    {
        values: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
    }
```

Query to retrieve results
If arguement = [1, 4, 5, 6] then`enter code here` Document 1 should be returned but not Document 2

IN clause is returning both documents

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [ARRAY_INTERSECT](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-intersect) function will work for you (combined with `ARRAY_COUNT`)? From docs: This function takes two or more arrays and returns the intersection of the input arrays as the result; that is, the array containing values that are present in all of the input arrays.

If I'm understanding you correctly, here's an example:

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_COUNT(ARRAY_INTERSECT([1,4,5,6],[1,4,5])) == ARRAY_COUNT([1,4,5]) as doesMatch,
    ARRAY_COUNT(ARRAY_INTERSECT([1,4,5,6],[1,2,3,5,6])) == ARRAY_COUNT([1,2,3,5,6]) as doesntMatch
    ;
```

Which would return:

```
[
  {
    "doesMatch": true,
    "doesntMatch": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EVERY or ANY AND EVERY described here https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#collection-op-every
This will handle duplicates and have flexibility to match the specific fields etc.

```
SELECT d.* FROM
default AS d
WHERE ANY AND EVERY v IN d.val SATISFIES v IN [1, 4, 5, 6]  END;
```

Range predicates (ANY or SOME, EVERY, and ANY AND EVERY or SOME AND EVERY) allow you to test a boolean condition over the elements or attributes of a collection or object(s). They each evaluate to a boolean value.

ANY or SOME is TRUE if the collection is non-empty and at least one element matches.

EVERY is TRUE if the collection is empty, or if the collection is non-empty and every element matches.

ANY AND EVERY or SOME AND EVERY is TRUE if the collection is non-empty and every element matches.